# A Tour of Golang: Slices are like references to arrays

Tags: go, out-of-memory

I'm doing the Tour of Go, and this part "Slices are like references to arrays." I haven't changed this code at all so I'm curious as to why it's running out of memory.

[image]

Comment: This does indeed crash on the official tour... how odd. OK what's even more odd is that removing even one (ANY one) of the `fmt.Println`'s fixes it. Also, replacing `fmt` import with `log` (and usage) fixes it too. (Sorry for the many edits).

Comment: I just tried again, and I'm still getting the error. I don't understand why my question got downvoted.

Comment: This is a known bug and has been reported in https://github.com/golang/tour/issues/541. You can work around it by modifying the source code insignificantly (introduce or remove an empty line, for instance).

Comment: It is working on go playground https://play.golang.org/p/ZKnXWR10bNO and on local.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's shouldn't crush, probably something is wrong with the tour website for few moments...
any way for now, 
[image]